# What is the correct idiom for asking people to have them packed more on the bus in order to have a space for you to get on the bus or metro?

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom (if there is one) for the question in the title.

Comment: I would like to ask the same for the seats on the bus (For example, 4 people who are occupying 5 seats row).

Comment: The bus drivers here yell 'Move down to the VERY end please'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**make room** (for someone or something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+room)

> to provide space for someone or something. Make room for Sam. He needs
>   a place to sit. Can you make room for this package?

'Make room, please' is suggested.